# Is there a way to make a faulty GPU more stable?

Tags: crash, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm having huge trouble with my GTX 970. It constantly and randomly crashes my computer, regardless of workload. Often it even freezes Win10's booting.

The computer is completely stable in Safe Mode, or in regular mode with the GPU uninstalled via the Device Manager so I'm 90% sure the GPU is the problem.

Already tried :

- New drivers, old drivers : tested pretty much all Nvidia from 388 to 436.
- BIOS is updated.
- PSU is a brand new 850W.
- Tried under-clocking everything to the max with Afterburner.
- Windows Memory Diagnostic & Chkdsk.
- Windows is NOT up-to-date : 1903 kill my computer completely.

Weird part is that sometime it can hold several weeks with no crash, including with intensive gaming session (making me think I finally solved the problem) but sooner or later it get back to crashing every few minutes, even with nothing going on but Windows desktop.

It's out of its warranty period, and I don't really have the spare money to buy something new. Searching for GPU stability on the net mainly return OverClocking stuff.

Is there some weird "no fail" tweaks for GPUs ? Or a setting telling the OS to simply disable the card when it crash instead of freezing and rebooting entirely ? I don't even care about performance at that point.

Comment: Are there any events in the logs after the crash? Is the card an Nvidia card or an Nvidia chipset from a third party like Dell for example?

Comment: Which logs exactly ? I'm not that good with hardware stuff and have been just following whatever I could find on the net.
If it's about the bootlog, freezes seem to happen when it try to load the GPU drivers. It also show a massive spam of
"BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED [at]cpu.inf,%intelppm.devicedesc%;Intel Processor" & 
"BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED [at]oem0.inf,%nvidia_dev.13c2%;NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970" from time to time.
The card itself is an MSI-made one.

Comment: What makes you believe that the GPU is at fault? Have you checked GPU temperatures (https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) at the same time as CPU temperatures(https://www.hwinfo.com/)? Have you run a memory test? (https://www.howtogeek.com/260813/how-to-test-your-computers-ram-for-problems/) Safe mode isn't really an indication of anything except *possibly* driver issues. There's a lot that gets left out of safe mode and it could even be your network card at fault.

Comment: I have kept Afterburner's monitor opened recently : crashes happen even at 35°, with 1-2% GPU usage (I changed fan settings in Afterburner, to keep it as cool as possible ... doesn't seem to do much). Memory test (and disk test) have both been made, forgot to mention it. I have to admit I never paid attention to CPU temperature however, will do from now. I'm blaming the GPU because no crash ever happen when it's disabled - but I'm open to other suggestions (that how I ended buying a new PSU, for naught).

Comment: So I monitored CPU temperature (after cleaning all fans just to be sure) : crashes still happen with CPU as low as 45°C and GPU at 40°C. Crashes don't happen with CPU as high as 90°C if the GPU is disabled. Tried underclocking the CPU a bit just in case, didn't improve stability.

Comment: Look at Windows Event logs.  Search "event viewer" in Windows 10 search.  Look at "Windows Logs"  I would start with System and look for Exclamation marks in red circle.   You can click column heading to sort by "Level"  This will group all exclamation marks and other types to make easier.  I would check all categories (Application, system, etc.) A critical even will usually have a description and error code to guide you.  Again, is the card made by Nvidia or by someone using Nvidia chips?

Comment: The card is made by MSI, not by Nvidia. The only critical events in the viewer are in "System" : all the same "Kernel Power", "Event ID : 41", "Task Category 63".